# gnuradio-companion ImportError: No module named main

Tags: python, gnuradio

I installed gnuradio. But when I want to use gnuradio-companion,
I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 99, in <module>
run_main()
File "/usr/local/bin/gnuradio-companion", line 87, in run_main
from gnuradio.grc.main import main
ImportError: No module named main
```

How I can improve this?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't properly install it, or you somehow didn't set the `$PYTHONPATH`, or … hard to say. How did you install GNU Radio, in which version, and on which OS are you?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04.
And I install use repository:
sudo apt-get install gnuradio

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR

My PYTHONPATH is

~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: Then you've got at least two competing installations, because the apt-get method will not install to `/usr/local`, but to `/usr/`.

Comment: What I must to do?

Comment: remember whether you've installed GNU Radio differently before? And if so, uninstall that non-apt installation.

Comment: The fact that you even have a pythonpath that points to /usr/local might indicated you've had a working GNU Radio installation before, or you've just done a lot of manual building of software. In any case, this is very much a problem with your own machine having remnants of multiple installations of software that are conflicting, so it's really not possible to help you any other way than recommending cleaning up your system

Comment: How correct clean system? How I must to delete gnuradio correct?

Comment: I don't know. That depends on how you've installed it.

Comment: I use:

sudo apt-get install gnuradio

Comment: no, you used something else  before, and have a second installation in /usr/local.

Comment: Can I delete /usr/local correct

Comment: I DON'T KNOW. It's your system.

Comment: Synaptic has an easy to install and stable version